# How to run a script from a mounted Google drive. The issue is that the google drive folder has a space in its name

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I mounted my drive using

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

I tried to run a script using

```
!python /content/drive/My Drive/script.py
```

But got this error

```
python3: can't open file '/content/drive/My': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I think the issue is that the 'My Drive' folder has a space. Is there a workaround?

Comment: How exactly are you running the script? My guess would be that you need to enclose the path in parentheses, i.e. `python "/content/drive/My Drive/script.py"`

Comment: That worked! I didn't know we could use quotes for specifying the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a backslash.

```
!python /content/drive/My\ Drive/script.py
```